# MongoDB aggregation filter on subdocument

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have 2 collections, orders and articles.

```
orders{
"_id": ObjectId("6225d9436e9c829d8ace723f"),
"name":"aa",
"date":"xx",
"articles": [ObjectId("6225d9436e9c829d8ace7240"), ObjectId("845621654as5d9sd29d8ace7240"),ObjectId("845621654as5d9sd29d8ace7240")]
}
```

and

```
 articles  
{
"_id" : ObjectId("6225d9436e9c829d8ace7240"),
"propertie2" : "zzzz",
"propertie1" : "abcd",
"usual_name" : "xxx",
"orders" : {
    "6225d9436e9c829d8ace723f" : {
        "num" : "Annexe I",        
        "priority" : "0",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum"
    },
    "6225d9446e9c829d8ace725c" : {
        "company" : "mycompany",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum2"
    }
    }
},
{
"_id" : ObjectId("845621654as5d9sd29d8ace7240"),
"propertie2" : "0000",
"propertie1" : "1111",
"usual_name" : "2222",
"orders" : {
    "6225d9436e9c829d8ace723f" : {
        "num" : "Annexe I",        
        "priority" : "0",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum",
        "otherkey": "othervalue"
    }
   }
}
```

I want to extract for 1 order, each article and data for this order.
For example, for order 6225d9436e9c829d8ace723f i want to get something like:

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("6225d9436e9c829d8ace723f"),
"name":"aa",
"date":"xx",
"articles":
[
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("6225d9436e9c829d8ace7240"),
    "propertie2" : "zzzz",
    "propertie1" : "abcd",
    "usual_name" : "xxx",
    "data" : {   
            "num" : "Annexe I",        
            "priority" : "0",
            "description" : "Lorem ipsum"
        }
    },
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("845621654as5d9sd29d8ace7240"),
    "propertie2" : "0000",
    "propertie1" : "1111",
    "usual_name" : "2222",
    "data" : {
            "num" : "Annexe I",        
            "priority" : "0",
            "description" : "Lorem ipsum",
            "otherkey": "othervalue"
       }
    }
]
}
```

So i tried this

```
db.orders.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        "_id":ObjectId("6225d9436e9c829d8ace723f")
    }   
},
{
    $lookup: {
        "from": "articles",
        "localField": "articles",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as" :"details"
    }      
}
,
{
      $project: {
          "articles":0,         
      }
}
])
```

But in my details results, i can not filter only on articles whose key matches the ObjecTId Order

```
 "details" : [ 
       {
"_id" : ObjectId("6225d9436e9c829d8ace7240"),
"propertie2" : "zzzz",
"propertie1" : "abcd",
"usual_name" : "xxx",
"orders" : {
    "6225d9436e9c829d8ace723f" : {
        "num" : "Annexe I",        
        "priority" : "0",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum"
    },
    "6225d9446e9c829d8ace725c" : {
        "company" : "mycompany",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum2"
    }
    }
}
}
```

Is it possible to filter on key 6225d9436e9c829d8ace723f and not on value ?

I want this

```
 "details" : [ 
       {
"_id" : ObjectId("6225d9436e9c829d8ace7240"),
"propertie2" : "zzzz",
"propertie1" : "abcd",
"usual_name" : "xxx",
"data" : {
            "num" : "Annexe I",        
        "priority" : "0",
        "description" : "Lorem ipsum"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You want to fetch all documents from articles where orders map has a key that is equal to order _id ?

Comment: Yes to fetch, and to keep only one order in article